# rxjs and angularJS - Referencing Component attributes using this within success callback inline function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rxjs

I have the following component

```
export class SubjectDetailComponent implements OnInit
{
    pageTitle: string = "Subject Detail";
    resultID: number = 0;
    pupilID: number = 0;
    subjectResult: ISubjectResult;
    errorMessage: string = "";
    private sub: Subscription;

    constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute,
                private _router: Router,
                private _subjectService : SubjectService) 
    {

    }

    ngOnInit(): void
    {
        this.sub = this._route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.resultID = params['result_id'];
        if ('pupil_id' in params)
        {
            this.pupilID = params['pupil_id'];
        }

        this.getSubject(this.resultID);
      });
    }

    getSubject(id: number)
    {
        this._subjectService.getSubject(id).subscribe(
            x => this.subjectResult = x,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);        
    }

}
```

And the following service (ignore the longhand map just playing around):

```
getSubject(id: number): Observable<ISubjectResult> {
    return this.getSubjects()
        .map(function(srs: ISubjectResult[]) 
                { 
                    let temp = srs.find(s => s.result_id == id);
                    return temp;
                });
}
```

My code works fine to update the subjectResult attribute in SubjectDetailComponent with the code above. However when I try and implement getSubject with an inline function instead of an arrow function (just because I can) like this:

```
 getSubject(id: number)
    {
        this._subjectService.getSubject(id).subscribe(
            function(x) { this.subjectResult = x; },
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);        
    }
```

The property subjectResult does not have the desired updated value. This is probably due to the scope and "this". Please can someone tell me how to reference a module/component's attributes from inside an inline function declaration.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the problem is with "this". An arrow function automatically uses the "this" context of the outer scope, unlike a normal function. Try using bind to access that scope, 
    this._subjectService.getSubject(id).bind(this).subscribe....